# Existence of sharps from a measurable

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

(Edited for more specific question)

I'm looking for a generalization of proof of the implication between "there exists a measurable cardinal $\kappa$" and "$0^\sharp$ exists". The proof I know uses Rowbottom's theorem:

**Theorem (Rowbottom).** If $\kappa$ is measurable, then given $f_i:[\kappa]^{m_i}\to\omega$ for $i<\omega$ and $m_i<\omega$ there is a subset $H\subseteq\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that every $f_i$ is constant on $[H]^{m_i}$.

And then I can build a club of indiscernibles for the model $\langle L_{\omega_1}, \in\rangle$.

My question is: how can I generalize the proof to any set $a$, to have an implication from "there exists a measurable cardinal $\kappa>\lambda$" to "$a^\sharp$ exists, for all $a\subseteq\lambda$"? I think we can start by this generalization of Rowbottom's theorem:

**Theorem (Rowbottom).** If $\kappa$ is measurable and $\lambda<\kappa$, then given $f_\alpha:[\kappa]^{m_\alpha}\to\lambda$ for $\alpha<\lambda$ and $m_\alpha<\omega$ there is a subset $H\subseteq\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that every $f_\alpha$ is constant on $[H]^{m_\alpha}$.

But then I don't see how to build a club of indiscernibles for $\langle L_{\omega_1}[a], \in, a\cap L_{\omega_1}[a]\rangle$.

(Previously I asked if there was a simpler proof than passing through Rowbottom's theorem, but I guess it wasn't exactly what I was looking for)

Comment: Do you know that the existence of $x^\#$ is equivalent to the existence of an elementary $j\colon L[x]\to L[x]$? That makes the whole proof quite instant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, you are right. I didn't think of that, but clearly is a way faster proof. Anyway, do you think that the approach with Rowbottom's theorem can be generalized?

Comment: I am not very good with combinatorical arguments, to be honest. So I never quite understood how these arguments work, in my mind there's just a deep translation of those into elementary embedding terms anyway. But, probably.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you! :)

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila one related question: you told me that the existence of $x^\sharp$ is equivalent to a nontrivial embedding $j: L[x] \to L[x]$, but a couple of days ago I found on an article somebody claiming that the existence of $x^\sharp$ is equivalent to a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:L(x)\to L(x)$… these two things are pretty different as far as I know, so I wanted to ask you for details about that, thank you in advance

Comment: Also, isn't it strange to get an elementary embedding $j:L[x]\to L[x]$ from large cardinals? Because you could do something like Jensen's coding forcing to preserve large cardinals and get $V=L[x]$, from which you get that there is no $j:L[x]\to L[x]$ nontrivial by Kunen's inconsistency... or maybe I'm saying very stupid things

Comment: Yeah, that's correct about $L(x)$, although when $x$ is a set of ordinals (e.g., a real number), the two models are equal. But it is the "more correct" definition indeed. As for the Jensen coding, why would the embedding be lifted *internally* from $V$ to $L[x]$?

Comment: Thank you @AsafKaragila, I didn't know that $L(x)=L[x]$ for $x$ a set of ordinals. It looks reasonable now, and everything works out fine! So, very good. For the Jensen coding, I'm not really sure, I was just talking to a friend and he mentioned "no, a $j:L[x]\to L[x]$ can't come from large cardinals because of that reasoning" so I tried to put it down in some way... but it's better if that doesn't work ahah. Thank you again Asaf, your answers are always precise and quick. Have a nice day!

Comment: The thing is that $L[x]$ will not have any (*large*) large cardinals exactly because $x$ is a real, so we can't preserve any embedding, as $j(x)=x$ in that case, and it would contradict Kunen's theorem.